# How to load a selected list of files using SAS macro

Tags: sas

I have a folder full of csv files (folder path `Path`). I have a SAS dataset `Name` which contains a list of selected file names. Dataset `Name` looks like the following:

```
FileName
File1
File3
File8
File9
...
```

I want to load every file listed on dataset `name` (`name1-name...`) and save it as sas dataset using the same name.

Can anyone teach me how to automate this process using macro please. I cannot figure out how to create a loop and do the following process one by one. Many thanks.

```
data Name1   ;
     infile 'Path\Name1.csv' delimiter = ','  truncover DSD lrecl=32767 firstobs=2 ;
         informat VAR1 $25. ;
         informat VAR2 yymmdd10. ;
         informat VAR3 best12.  ;

         format VAR1 $25. ;
         format VAR2 yymmdd10. ;
         format VAR3 best12.  ;

         input
                  VAR1 $
                  var2
                  var3
      ;
run;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create code that imports correctly for one file (you've provided above).
2. Change code to take macro variables instead of default values.

   ```
   %let name=name1;

   data &name;
   infile "Path\&name..csv" delimiter = ','  truncover DSD lrecl=32767 firstobs=2 ;
   informat VAR1 $25. VAR2 yymmdd10. VAR3 best12.  ;
   format VAR1 $25.  VAR2 yymmdd10.  VAR3 best12.  ;

   input VAR1 $ var2 var3;
   run;
   ```
3. Create a macro that takes parameters

   ```
   %macro import_file(name);
   data &name;
   infile "Path\&name..csv" delimiter = ','  truncover DSD lrecl=32767 firstobs=2 ;
   informat VAR1 $25. VAR2 yymmdd10. VAR3 best12.  ;
   format VAR1 $25.  VAR2 yymmdd10.  VAR3 best12.  ;

   input VAR1 $ var2 var3;
   run;
   %mend;
   ```
4. Use call execute within your dataset to execute macro.

   ```
   data _null_;
   set files;
   str=catt('%import_file(', file_name, ');');
   call execute(str);
   run;
   ```